# Windows 10 - Cursor can't click on other windows

Tags: windows-10, mouse

So recently I've had this problem on my personal Windows 10 laptop where the mouse cursor still moves perfectly fine but it only seems to respond to clicks within one process/window (and it's not always the same process), almost as if it's getting "locked in". The best way to describe it is to imagine a modal window where your cursor works perfectly within that modal window but you can't click on anything outside of that modal window and the cursor won't change/react to anything outside of that window, either.

Now take that same behavior and just imagine it's a browser or maybe Windows Explorer or the Windows task manager something. There's clearly no modal window but it acts like the current window is one.

And if I hit Ctrl+Alt+Del to bring up that Windows menu where I can select the task manager/etc, and click once in there, everything goes back to normal for a few minutes. I can exit out of that screen and click on all the other windows just fine. But after a while (amount of time is very random - sometimes seconds or sometimes minutes), the same behavior occurs again.

I was planning on just reformatting my laptop and figured it was just a fluke with it or one of its software packages, but then this problem just occurred on my work laptop (also Windows 10) this morning (which I keep fairly pristine - minimal software).

On my work laptop, it occurred on the regular Windows explorer process (taskbar icons were responsive to the cursor but nothing else was until I did the Ctrl+Alt+Del-and-cancel trick).

The only common factor between the two laptops was an old Logitech mouse that I happened to use on both of them, but I've used it on my work laptop lots of times without any problems before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the mouse.

Comment: have you try to kill and start explorer